# Ubuntu random command eats up 100% cup usage

Tags: security, drupal, remote-access, elf

I have set up a ubuntu server in cloud. Recently I received an alert telling me that the CPU usage of my server is always 100%. I tried to investigate the incident but I have no clue what's going on. I am hoping some one can point me to the right direction based on what i have found.

**Here is what I can find:**

- **Random command**:  I run "htop" to inspect which process is
  consuming my cpu resource. I found that  a random command (named "tbq", as
  you can see in the [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3DiG.png)) by "root" continues consuming my cpu
  resource. I tried to kill it with "kill -9 pid", but it revives
  instantly with a different random command. I can only stop the
  process with "kill -STOP pid".
- **elf file:**
  I then inspect the syslog of my server, i found that the following command keeps running by "cron":

  CMD (cd /usr/share/nginx/html/drupal-dev/sites/default/files;./share)

I navigate to the directory, there are few strange files with random name but with same content. I open the file with "nano", the followings are the first few lines of the file:

```
7f45 4c46 0201 0103 0000 0000 0000 0000
0200 3e00 0100 0000 9008 4000 0000 0000
4000 0000 0000 0000 28c6 3f00 0000 0000
0000 0000 4000 3800 0600 4000 2100 1e00
```

I search through the internet and know that this should be a ELF file. Though, I do not understand what's going on inside this ELF file

- **Drupalgeddon2**:
  I realize that the file is located under "drupal-dev", i have also searched in google with keywords "drupal, elf". And i found this [post](https://www.volexity.com/blog/2018/04/16/drupalgeddon-2-profiting-from-mass-exploitation/).

It seems that there is a security hole inside drupal, which hackers can exploit it to hijack my server, and use my server resource as a node for mining cryptocurrency.

**Question:**
I am not sure whether "Drupalgeddon2" is my case. can someone point me to a right direction to investigate deeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using administrator account navigate to "**Management Menu > Reports > Available Updates**" or you could just go to ***www.yourwebsitename.com*/admin/reports/updates** using the address bar of your browser.

- If you are using Drupal 7 your Drupal core version needs to be at
  **least 7.58**
- If you are using Drupal 8 your Drupal core version needs to be at
  **least 8.5.1**

If you are using below these versions, you can be sure that your server was exploited using the **Drupalgeddon2** exploit.

When I was in the same situation as you I just downloaded the database and the Drupal source code form the server, updated the Drupal core and uploaded the source code and database to another server.

This fixed my problem

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. I am wondering whether "Drupalgeddon2" will duplicate itself and infect other files? If there is a possibility of it, should i remove all of my drupal source code?

Comment: Usually the infected code is inside the Drupal core files, so when you update your Drupal core files the malicious code should be removed once and for all.

From your old drupal instalaltion you leave only the 'sites' directory, this is where your **custom** + **contributed** **drupal** modules, your **themes** and your **files** live.But I recommend to change the server, because if files outside Drupal are infected it will require a good server expert to pinpoint exactly where the malicious code has spread to...

Comment: Oh, thanks for you help. My concern is resolved now. Really save my days.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more than just Drupal. 
It’s more of a securing the server and hardening it before you install anything such as webserver, database server or Drupal.

I would invest time going through this check lists to clean it up then lock it down.

**First deal with the server**

https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

**Then deal with Drupal**

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/security/your-drupal-site-got-hacked-now-what